# JavaFX.fxml.LoadException

Tags: javafx, netbeans, builder, scene

I'm new to javafx and trying to make a functional login application with javafx. When I run the default codes by netbeans for javafx fxml application, it runs perfectly but when I make my own application with scene builder and code simple logic it gives error.

**Here's the error**

```
Executing C:\Users\Ovonel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Digi_Library\dist\run1053353439\Digi_Library.jar using platform C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/Ovonel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Digi_Library/dist/run1053353439/Digi_Library.jar!/digi_library/login/Login.fxml:11

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at digi_library.login.Login.start(Login.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at digi_library.login.LoginController.<init>(LoginController.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application digi_library.login.Login
Java Result: 1
```

**Here's the Controller:**

```
package digi_library.login;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    private TextField usernameTF;
    private PasswordField passwordTF;

    String username = usernameTF.getText();
    String password = passwordTF.getText();

    // Legit User Details
    String uname = "adming";
    String pass = "root";

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    private void Login(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        try
        {
        if(username.equals(uname) && password.equals(pass))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Legit user, login in!");
        }
        else if(username.isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter username");
        }
        else if(password.isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter password");
        }
        else if(username.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter username as well as password to login");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Denied!");
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void Cancel(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

**Here's the Fxml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="310.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="digi_library.login.LoginController">
   <children>
      <PasswordField layoutX="100.0" layoutY="180.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="Password" />
      <TextField layoutX="100.0" layoutY="115.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="Username" />
      <ImageView fitHeight="40.0" fitWidth="40.0" layoutX="180.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../resources/icons/icons8_Lock_100px.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Button layoutX="50.0" layoutY="256.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Login" />
      <Button layoutX="250.0" layoutY="256.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Cancel" />
      <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" layoutX="65.0" layoutY="118.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../resources/icons/icons8_User_24px.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" layoutX="65.0" layoutY="183.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../resources/icons/icons8_Password_1_24px.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

**Here's the main java file**

```
package digi_library.login;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Login extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I tried fx:root option in Scene Builder but it didn't work. This error is also showing up when I use the jfoenix.jar for my project. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers). You need to inject the text fields into the controller, using `@FXML` in the controller and `fx:id` in the FXML. You need to move the initialization of `username` and `password` to the event handler (or just declare them there): you need to get their text when the user has typed in there, not when they are first created.

Comment: Off-topic: don't mix different UI toolkits. Use [`Alert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) or [`Dialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html), not `JOptionPane` (which is a swing component). Trying to show a `JOptionPane` on the FX Application Thread will hang your application on many platforms.

Comment: By the way I am using JDK 8, does it has to do something with javafx?

Comment: Thank you very much. The program is working perfectly! Java swing application was easy....well javafx is bit tricky. Thanks once again!